# Jdbi SqlObject Kotlin Return Types

Tags: kotlin, jdbi3

Good day smart people. I am currently having trouble attempting to use the JDBI Kotlin SqlObject plugin with a Kotlin interface class.

When setting up the following dao in an .kt interface file

```
interface DTaskStatusDao {
   @Timestamped
   @SqlUpdate(ADD_TASK_STATUS_ENTRY)
   suspend fun insertTask(@BindKotlin @BindMethods taskStatus: TaskStatus<*>)
}
```

and using the resulting DAO object as such

```
val dao = jdbi.onDemand(DTaskStatusDao::class): Void
dao.insertTask(it)
```

I get the following exception :
`DTaskStatusDao.insertTask method is annotated with @SqlUpdate so should return void, boolean, or Number but is returning`

Since Kotlin doesn't allow using Java primitives, so I assume that only option is to write the dao interface in .java files only? Or am I missing something else?

I have also attempting using different Kotlin comparable types, i.e. Number, Boolean but all seems to boiled down to a java.Object in the JDBI type resoution.

The problem does not arise using non primitives in SQLQuery annotations. Any applicable feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JDBI's SqlObject library, to utilize Kotlin-style primitives (i.e. Unit, Int, Boolean) as a return type for annotated methods (such as the one mention in the OP) one could expose a target interface as a [mixin](https://jdbi.org/#_combining_sql_object_and_the_core_api) simply by having it extend the core SqlObject interface.

In the case of the OP's example, the answer would to utilize the following:

```
interface DTaskStatusDao : SqlObject {
   @Timestamped
   @SqlUpdate(ADD_TASK_STATUS_ENTRY)
   suspend fun insertTask(@BindKotlin @BindMethods taskStatus: TaskStatus<*>)
}
```

Deeper research into the original JDBI repository reveals a unit test that also exhibits this solution.

[Kotlin SqlObject Interface Example](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/blob/6456b974f9acbdc8cc04c84ac87be63b2ca809df/kotlin-sqlobject/src/test/kotlin/org/jdbi/v3/sqlobject/kotlin/KotlinSqlObjectPluginTest.kt#L51C15-L51C23)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).